# Vue: passing `this.foo()` as event listener method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my `created()` hook, I have the following code:

```
{
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.someMethod)
  }, 
  methods: {
    someMethod(event) {
      console.log(event)
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

The console log is not firing. What am I doing wrong? The following works:

```
const someMethod = event => {
  console.log(event)
}

export default {
  ... other stuff
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.someMethod)
  },
}
```

EDIT:
There seems to be some confusion about what I'm asking. I'm *not* asking how I can use `this` keyword inside the function. You use the arrow function for that. What I'm asking is I can't seem to pass the object's method as the callback function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't think so, the OP isn't using `this` in the method. (And doesn't Vue even autobind them iirc?). He's complaining that the method doesn't run at all, not that `// do stuff` (which might use `this`) doesn't work.

Comment: @Bergi retracted, good catch

Comment: The initial code works in an empty project. I suspect something else is going on. Are there any [event modifiers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) in your project like `stop`?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I do have event modifiers, but they're attached to inputs and other HTML elements, not `window`, so I don't see how that'd cause this to happen.

Comment: It would, but only if they were focused. I'd recommend debugging this by removing components until it works, or by starting with an empty project and adding components until it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

You should set a callback as a second parameter to the `addEventListener` function and inside it call your method, it's recommended to use arrow function in order to access `this` in callback scope :

```
created() {
window.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{

    this.someMethod(e)

})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The catch is in the following code

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.someMethod)
  },
```

`someMethod` is the `fn` and the object who is calling it refers to `this`.

Now whats the value of `this` here. The basic definition state about `dynamic` scope comes into play, dynamic scoped `fn` will have the value of `this` when the get called and not where they are written.

So when `keydown` occurs it's actually when things happened and works as per input which means - `this` is `window` and not the `vue` context.

To solve this issue we need to make that `this` to be lexical scoped which means value of `this` should be where the `method` is written.

**ES6 Arrow**  is good option as mentioned in the first answer

```
created() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', () => { 
    // Arrow method makes the value of `this` lexically scoped.
    // If you use normal fn , then again it get dynamically scoped
    this.someMethod()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  created() {
  let vm = this // could not use this keyword directly in eventlistener
  window.addEventListener('keydown', vm.someMethod)
  },
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.